# Is it possible to add values from list to input form field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I got assignment where I need to add values to input field from list using jQuery UI (drag&drop).

I've managed to apply drag&drop functionality but when it comes to "gluing values" to input field for me it seems quite a challenge.

So, here is some random list generated from database.

```
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="ui-widget list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      Another Value
      <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">A Value</span>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-widget list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      Epic Value
      <span class="ui-widget-content badge badge-primary badge-pill">E</span>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-widget list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      Some Value
      <span class="ui-widget-content badge badge-primary badge-pill">V</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Here is script

```
$(function() {
  $(".ui-widget").draggable({
    revert: function(event, ui) {

      $(this).data("ui-draggable").originalPosition = {
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      };

      return !event;

    }
  });
  $("#droppable").droppable();
})
```

And now million dollar question? Is it possible to glue span value to input field and send it to server?

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Svinjica/4v3cf6L7/)

Thank you for your time and help :)

**UPDATE**

With massive help from fellow Twisty he did managed to drop value from list to input field. Only question remains how to append values from list (or to be more precise from badge). 
Now, I'm able to insert only one value because with every dropped value I'm erasing previous instead appending new one. So, my question is this: Is it possible to append values from dropped values inside input field?

```
$(function() {
  $(".ui-widget").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $(".drop").droppable({
    accept: ".list-group-item",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-hover": "drag-hover"
    },
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      var badge = ui.draggable.find(".badge").text();
      $(this).val(badge);

    }
  });
});
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Svinjica/4v3cf6L7/)

Comment: There are a number of issues. First, let's start with IDs, they must be unique for each element. You cannot have 2 `droppable` ids. Second, you have nothing bound to the `drop` callback that would enter the data into the field.

Comment: Thank you for feedback, i really appreciate it. Can u please point me in right direction regarding second issue

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear what your "assignment" is, yet if you want to drag an object to a text field and populate it, it would be done in `drop` event.

See More: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mxnt74kh/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(".ui-widget").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $(".drop").droppable({
    accept: ".list-group-item",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-hover": "drag-hover"
    },
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      var badge = ui.draggable.find(".badge").text();
      $(this).val(badge);
      ui.draggable.remove();
    }
  });
});
```

It's not all necessary so I'll let you figure out what is needed or not.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I'm just wondering about two things. Is it possible to add values and not overwrite it and second to preserve draggable element and not to remove it. Besides that everything is perfect and it will be accepted

Comment: @Svinjica yes these are all things that can be done. You'd want to capture the current value of the field and that append to it instead of replacing it. Yes, you can revert the position of the drag item at the end of drop.